# Redirect a domain to another without Change in URL in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have two web server one is Ruby and  other is simple WordPress site. Now i want to redirect a page of ruby  site to a wordpress page with out changing URL. 
so what i want is if ruby site is abc.com and wordpress site is xyz.com so
if i type abc.com than redirect to xyz.com but it should be abc.com in url.

Ruby is served by nginx. i am able to redirect to wordpress site but URL is also changed.

Comment: The command you need is proxy_pass - read up on it. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

Comment: Thanks, i am able to do this with the help of proxy pass and upstream.

Comment: Once you get it working, please let other people with the same problem know the solution by posting and accepting it as your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i was able to do this, there is very simple solution for this.

```
http {
    upstream myproject {
        server abc.com;
    }

    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xyz.com;
        location /about-us {
            proxy_pass http://myproject;
        }
     }
}
```

Hope it helps others